# Partial data returned by OpenQuery in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle11g, dblink, openquery

I have a Link server exposed on SQL server of a Oracle Database and I am using the following query to retrieve data. MsgCol is of type LONG in oracle. The query is always returning 100 Character but the original data is way bigger than that.

Please suggest where the things are going wrong.

```
SELECT MsgCol FROM OPENQUERY(OleLink,'SELECT MsgCol  FROM repo_View_Link  WHERE Ref_No=''00001521''')
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert "LONG" to "varchar2" on the Oracle side?

Comment: Check if this helps. "https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/long-data-truncated-when-migrating-from-oracle-to-sql-server" Read till the end.

Comment: Solved by Changing the size of below registry to 2500 which was by default 100   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDb10g_home\OLEDB

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ebecd1a-3928-4c61-9e6f-c91f1c64b88c/ole-db-source-for-oracle-long-datatype?forum=sqlintegrationservices